# how to find a triangular matrix by permutation

Tags: r, matrix

I have a square matrix which I know can become a triangular one by permutation, what would be the Matrix::function call to get the triangular one ?

I have thus B as

```
B <- matrix(c(0,5,6,1,2,3,0,0,9),3,3)
```

and want to get a function that renders as result

```
B[,c(2,1,3)]
```

Comment: Can you include some input and expected output (you might want to consider reading up on reproducible examples and [ask])?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You could try with

```
B[, order(sapply(1:ncol(B), function(x) rle(B[,x]==0)$lengths[1]*rle(B[,x]==0)$values[1]))]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    2    5    0
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

This orders the columns of the matrix according to the number of consecutive zeros (counted from the top row downwards), with the shortest sequence of zeros first.